# C# Is there a "Rule" that I can set on an enum that every item in it has to have a specific attribute

Tags: c#

I have an enum where every item has a description:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Description1")]
    Item1,
    [Description("Description2")]
    Item2
}
```

Is there a way to make a rule that every new item in this enum has to have a description too?

Comment: See duplicate. Use [CSharpSyntaxVisitor<TResult>.VisitEnumMemberDeclaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxvisitor-1.visitenummemberdeclaration) instead of `CSharpSyntaxWalker.VisitPropertyDeclaration` that's used by the author of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, the C# compiler (Roslyn) is modular and extensible.

You want to create a [`CodeAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.codeactions.codeaction?view=roslyn-dotnet) in a code analysis project, and reference it from your main project. In the code action you have access to the entire project's syntax tree and semantic analysis, which makes what you want relatively trivial.